Configure audience to be verified in Blazor WASM with OIDC
I am using OIDC with a third party IdP for authentication for my Blazor WASM application. I use the oidc middleware with:
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Configure your authentication provider options here.
    // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
    builder.Configuration.Bind("MyIdpSettings", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
});

And in my appsettings.json:
  "MyIdpSettings": {
    "Authority": "[AUTHORITY AS URL]",
    "ClientId": "[CLIENT ID AS GUID]"
  }

The app correctly redirects to IdP. IdP correctly authenticates and redirects back to WASM app. The WASM app receives the JWT for processing, and tries to validate.
Validation fails around line 11120 of AuthenticationService.js (MSAL)
 t.validateJwtAttributes = function (e, r, i, o, s, a) {
     o || (o = 0),
         s || (s = parseInt(Date.now() / 1e3));
     var u = t.parseJwt(e).payload;
     if (!u.iss)
         return n.Log.error("JoseUtil._validateJwt: issuer was not provided"),
             Promise.reject(new Error("issuer was not provided"));
     if (u.iss !== r)
         return n.Log.error("JoseUtil._validateJwt: Invalid issuer in token", u.iss),
             Promise.reject(new Error("Invalid issuer in token: " + u.iss));
     if (!u.aud)
         return n.Log.error("JoseUtil._validateJwt: aud was not provided"),
             Promise.reject(new Error("aud was not provided"));
     if (!(u.aud === i || Array.isArray(u.aud) && u.aud.indexOf(i) >= 0))  <<---- FAILS HERE
         return n.Log.error("JoseUtil._validateJwt: Invalid audience in token", u.aud),
             Promise.reject(new Error("Invalid audience in token: " + u.aud));
     if (u.azp && u.azp !== i)
         return n.Log.error("JoseUtil._validateJwt: Invalid azp in token", u.azp),
             Promise.reject(new Error("Invalid azp in token: " + u.azp));

The audience that comes back from my IdP is the audience that I set in the config tools provided by my IdP (i.e. the audience in the JWT is 'correct' and as expected).
The MSAL javascript, however, expects the audience to be the 'ClientId' specified in AddOidcAuthentication middleware configuration.
In other words, u.aud above is '[MY CUSTOM AUDIENCE]' while i above is '[CLIENT ID AS GUID]'.
How do I specify a value for audience that MSAL will use to validate the token?
I have tried, in the configuration of the middleware, something like:
options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters["audience"] = "[CUSTOM AUDIENCE]";

But that had no effect. (I think this changes the request to the IdP...? Not the way that MSAL validates the response...?)

But the appsettings is not complete for request a token with custom audience. "Audience" is the downstream api project which also registered in IDP. This api should have specific "scopes".
So you only need to add the specific scope, then the corresponding "audience" will be in the token.
options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("downstream_api.read");  //The scoped you configured for downstreampi in IDP

And there shouldn't be audience validation happen in frontend (WASM). The validation happen in backend api to check the token has the corresponding "Audience" and "Scopes".
Besides, I have used identity server and keycloak without any issue. It may be helpful if we know what the IDP is and how the "Audience" is configured.

Thank you for your response. I kind of get your first point, and I'll go away and look at that a bit. But your second point: 'there shouldn't be audience validation in WASM'; the built-in Microsoft AuthenticationService.js that I snipped above is definitely validating the token in the WASM, and it's failing when the audience it expects doesn't match the audience in the token... and I can't figure out how to set the expected audience in the WASM so that it doesn't fail. You could probably breakpoint the t.validateJwtAttributes line in your own project and see it in progress.
